# finding the perfect cube

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I had to find the least positive integer $k$ such that $2^4 \cdot 3^5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11^2 \cdot k$ is a perfect cube which is $2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 7^2 \cdot 11$.

Now I need to write $2^4 \cdot 3^5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11^2 · k$ as a perfect cube using the value of $k$.

I'm confused as to how to use the value of $k$ to find the perfect square.

Comment: Do you understand *why* $k=2^2\cdot3\cdot7^2\cdot11$?

Comment: Do you know how to quickly and easily tell from the prime factorisation of a number whether that number is a perfect cube? Or are you just wondering what "write a number as a perfect cube" means?

Comment: To do a simpler example, $2^4k$ is a perfect cube when $k=2^2$, in which case $2^4k=2^4\cdot2^2=2^6=(2^2)^3=4^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be a "perfect cube" the prime factorization of a number must be primes all to a power a multiple of 3.

For example, $2^3= 8$ is a perfect cube but so is $2^6= 64= 4^3$.

Here you are given the number $2^4\cdot 3^5\cdot 7^1\cdot 11^2$.  The smallest multiple of that that is a perfect cube is $2^6\cdot 3^6\cdot 7^3\cdot 11^3$ which means it must be multiplied by $2^2\cdot 3^1\cdot 7^2\cdot 11^1$.

The cube root of $2^6\cdot 3^6\cdot 7^3\cdot 11^3$ is $2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 7^1\cdot 11^1$.